# When using search filters in Vue JS is there a way to search against objects in the array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very basic search filter which allows a user to perform a search for a wine using the wine name and the location of the producer.

However, I would also like the search to work with a list of objects in an array (grapes). Is this possible and how would this be done? My current code is as below.

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search products">
  <ul>
      <li v-for="product in filteredProducts">
         <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
        <span>{{product.location}}</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Then my Vue code is:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            search:'',
            products: [
              { 
                name: 'The Black Sock',
                location: 'Australia',
                grapes: ['shiraz']
              },
              { 
                name: 'Goat Roti',
                location: 'France',
                grapes: ['Shiraz' , 'Mourvedre']
              },
              { 
                name: 'Amon Ra',
                location: 'New Zealand',
                grapes: ['Chardonnay', 'Riesling']
              }
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredProducts:function(){
            return this.products.filter((product) => {
              return product.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||  product.location.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
            });
        }

        filteredSearch.sort((a, b) => {
              if (a.name< b.name)
                  return -1;
              if (a.name> b.name)
                  return 1;
              return 0;
        });
        return filteredSearch
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in what you want to search no matter if name, location or grapes, if you type in for example `shiraz` it will display all elements that includes shiraz in `name`, `location` or `grapes`

```js
let vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            search:'',
            products: [
              { 
                name: 'The Black Sock',
                location: 'Australia',
                grapes: ['shiraz']
              },
              { 
                name: 'Goat Roti',
                location: 'France',
                grapes: ['Shiraz' , 'Mourvedre']
              },
              { 
                name: 'Amon Ra',
                location: 'New Zealand',
                grapes: ['Chardonnay', 'Riesling']
              }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
       sortByName(a,b){
          return a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase());
       }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredProducts:function(){
           let comperator = this.sortByName;
           if(this.search == "") return this.products.sort(comperator);
           let search = this.search.toLowerCase();
           return this.products.filter(({name, location, grapes}) => name.toLowerCase().includes(search) || location.toLowerCase().includes(search) || grapes.find(el => el.toLowerCase().includes(search))).sort(comperator);
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search products">
  <ul>
      <li v-for="product in filteredProducts">
         <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{product.location}}</p>
        <p>{{product.grapes}}</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @ifaruki Your answer helps me learn. I am now trying to sort the order of the out put by name :)

Comment: @Al-76 i have updated answer. user `.localeCompare()` with `.toLowerCase()` when you compare strings

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance. I am still learning and you have helped me a lot to begin to understand Vue better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes` to check if something exists in the array or not.

You can use `filter` with `includes` like this.

```js
const products = [
              { 
                name: 'The Black Sock',
                location: 'Australia',
                grapes: ['shiraz']
              },
              { 
                name: 'Goat Roti',
                location: 'France',
                grapes: ['Shiraz' , 'Mourvedre']
              },
              { 
                name: 'Amon Ra',
                location: 'New Zealand',
                grapes: ['Chardonnay', 'Riesling']
              }
            ]
            
const selectedGrapes =  'Shiraz'  

const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => product.grapes.includes(selectedGrapes))

console.log(filteredProducts)
```